# Godot signal is not deleted, after I reopen Godot it is there again

Tags: runtime-error, godot

I'm a beginner learning to make Games at Godot, and I'm following the tutorial "Your First 2D Game". I'm having an issue with Signal and I'm using C# as my script language.

My Problem:
I delete the New_Game() and Game_Over() method attached as signal to the Player.cs because I want to use these methods in Main.cs (the parent).

The Problem is after I delete these methods from Signals tab, Save the application, Close the application, and Reopen it... I noticed that they are reappearing again, as if I have not deleted them!

There's one more important thing I need to tell you: When I Right Click and select "Go to Method", it doesn't open the script Main.cs!!!

It seems there's some bug on the platform, or something that I don't know that is causing it.

My main screen - You will see both methods duplicated, one attached to Main.cs and the other two attached to the Player.cs(these are the ones I want to delete):
[image]

Error caused in the game because of that:
[image]

New_Game() attached to the Main.cs:
[image]

Game_Over() attached to the Main.cs:
[image]

New_Game() attached to Player.cs:
[image]

Game_Over() attached to Player.sc:
[image]

Now, I will put here all my scripts!

Main.cs:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class Main : Node
{
// Declare member variables here. Examples:
// private int a = 2;
// private string b = "text";

#pragma warning disable 649
[Export]
public PackedScene MobScene;
#pragma warning restore 649

public int Score;

// Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
public override void _Ready()
{ 
    GD.Randomize();
    New_Game();
}

//  // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
//  public override void _Process(float delta)
//  {
//      
//  }

public void Game_Over()
{
    GetNode<Timer>("MobTimer").Stop();
    GetNode<Timer>("ScoreTimer").Stop();
}

public void New_Game()
{
    Score = 0;

    var player = GetNode<Player>("/root/Main/Player");
    var startPosition = GetNode<Position2D>("/root/Main/StartPosition");
    player.Start(startPosition.Position);

    //GetNode<Timer>("/root/Main/StartTimer").Start();
    Timer StartTimer = GetNode<Timer>("/root/Main/StartTimer");
    StartTimer.Start();
}

public void On_StartTimer_Timeout()
{
    GetNode<Timer>("MobTimer").Start();
    GetNode<Timer>("ScoreTimer").Start();
}

public void On_ScoreTimer_Timeout()
{
    Score++;
}

public void On_MobTimer_Timeout()
{
    //Create a new instance of the Mob Scene
    var mob = (Mob)MobScene.Instance();

    //Choose a random Location on Path2D
    var mobSpawnLocation = GetNode<PathFollow2D>("MobPath/MobSpawnLocation");
    mobSpawnLocation.Offset = GD.Randi();

    //Set the mon's direction perpendicular to the path direction.
    float direction = mobSpawnLocation.Rotation + Mathf.Pi / 2;

    //Set the mob's position to a random location.
    mob.Position = mobSpawnLocation.Position;

    //Add some randomness to the direction
    direction += (float)GD.RandRange(-Mathf.Pi / 4, Mathf.Pi / 4);
    mob.Rotation = direction;

    // Choose the velocity.
    var velocity = new Vector2((float)GD.RandRange(150.0, 250.0), 0);
    mob.LinearVelocity = velocity.Rotated(direction);

    // Spawn the mob by adding it to the Main scene.
    AddChild(mob);

}
}
```

Player.cs:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class Player : Area2D
{
// Declare member variables here. Examples:
// private int a = 2;
// private string b = "text";

//How fast the player will move (pixel/sec).
[Export]
public int Speed = 400;
[Signal]
public delegate void Hit();
// Size of the game window.
public Vector2 ScreenSize;

public int Score;
// Called when the node enters the scene tree 
for the first time.
public override void _Ready()
{
    ScreenSize = GetViewportRect().Size;
    Hide(); //Player is hidden when the game 
starts
}

// Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed 
time since the previous frame.
public override void _Process(float delta)
{
    var velocity = Vector2.Zero; //Tha Player's 
 movement vector

    if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_right"))
    {
        velocity.x += 1;
    }
    if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_left"))
    {
        velocity.x -= 1;
    }
    if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_down"))
    {
        velocity.y += 1;
    }
    if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_up"))
    {
        velocity.y -= 1;
    }

    var animatedSprite = GetNode<AnimatedSprite>("AnimatedSprite");

    if (velocity.Length() > 0)
    {
        velocity = velocity.Normalized() * Speed;
        animatedSprite.Play();

    }
    else
    {
        animatedSprite.Stop();
    }

    Position += velocity * delta;
    Position = new Vector2(
        x: Mathf.Clamp(Position.x, 0, ScreenSize.x),
        y: Mathf.Clamp(Position.y, 0, ScreenSize.y)
        );

    if (velocity.x != 0)
    {
        animatedSprite.Animation = "walk";
        animatedSprite.FlipV = false;
        animatedSprite.FlipH = velocity.x < 0; 
 //Here I'm doing a boolean test
    }
    else if (velocity.y != 0)
    {
        animatedSprite.Animation = "up";
        animatedSprite.FlipV = velocity.y > 0; 
 //Here I'm doing a boolean test
    }
}

public void On_Player_Body_Entered(PhysicsBody2D body)
{
    Hide(); //Player disappears after being hit.
    EmitSignal(nameof(Hit));//On_Player_Hit()
    //Must be deferred as we can't change physics properties on a physics callback.
    GetNode<CollisionShape2D>("CollisionShape2D").SetDeferred("disabled", true);
} 

//Reset the player when starting the game  
public void Start(Vector2 pos)
{
    Position = pos;
    Show();
    GetNode<CollisionShape2D>("CollisionShape2D").Disabled = false;
}
}
```

Mob.cs:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class Mob : RigidBody2D
{
// Declare member variables here. Examples:
// private int a = 2;
// private string b = "text";

// Called when the node enters the scene tree 
for the first time.
public override void _Ready()
{
    var animSprite = GetNode<AnimatedSprite>("AnimatedSprite");
    animSprite.Playing = true;
    string[] mobTypes = animSprite.Frames.GetAnimationNames();
    animSprite.Animation = mobTypes[GD.Randi() % mobTypes.Length];
}

// // Called every frame. 'delta' is the 
elapsed time since the previous frame.
// public override void _Process(float delta)
// {
//     
//  }

public void OnVisibilityNotifier2DScreenExited()
{
    QueueFree();
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't only delete it from code. You need to select the node in the editor and go to the signals tab.  From there you need to right click the deleted signal in question and disconnect it.

Comment: I did all you told me! Even with no code at the Player.cs and deleting the signals at the Signals tab, I save the software, close, open again, and those 2 signals appears there again. I don't know if the Godot have some cache or something like that I need to clean up in order to fix this.